# Optimize this jQuery tab controller further

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I optimize this code further?  Goal is to edit "js-tab" in one place.  [This](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/) is what I tried to follow.

Full code [here](http://codepen.io/TDogg137/pen/yKzlj/).

```
var ToggleTab = {

init: function() {
    this.tab = $(".js-tab");
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    this.tab.on("click", this.toggleTab);
    //this.tab.on("click", $.proxy(this.toggleTab, this));
},

toggleTab: function(e) { 
    var showTab = $(this).data("tab-content");
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".js-tab").each(function() {
        if ($(this).data("tab-content") === showTab) {
           $(".js-tab-" + showTab).removeClass("hide");                
        } else {
            $(".js-tab-" + $(this).data("tab-content")).addClass("hide");
        }
    });
}

};

$(function() {

    ToggleTab.init();

});
```

Comment: Optimise for what - speed, memory, source file size? And what would be an acceptable value at which point you'll stop optimising? Unless you can answer these, you're wasting your time.

Comment: An acceptable value is already in his question: " Goal is to edit "js-tab" in one place."

Comment: Just like Greg said.. also I'd like to use this.tab (like in bindEvents) inside toggleTab but I would get "undefined".  Another way to say is I'd like to define a bunch of properties on init and reference them within the methods below.  Hopefully I'm making sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've always been partial to writing JavaScript classes that take a root element:

```
function TabController() {
    // Maintain reference to "this" in event handlers
    this.toggleTab = this.toggleTab.bind(this);
}

TabController.prototype = {

    $element: null,

    constructor: TabController,

    init: function(element) {
        this.$element = $(element).on("click", ".js-tab", this.toggleTab);

        return this;
    },

    toggleTab: function(event) {
        var that = this,
            showTab = event.target.getAttribute("data-tab-content");
        event.preventDefault();

        this.$element.find(".js-tab").each(function() {
            var tabContent = this.getAttribute("data-tab-content");

            if (tabContent === showTab) {
                that.$element.find(".js-tab-" + showTab).removeClass("hide");                
            } else {
                that.$element.find(".js-tab-" + tabContent).addClass("hide");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Plus, I like to replace jQuery API calls that wrap cross browser native DOM methods  -- e.g. `$(foo).data("bar")` most times can be replaced with `element.getAttribute("data-bar")`.

And to use:

```
// using document.documentElement means you don't need a jQuery dom-ready event handler
var tabs = new TabController().init(document.documentElement);
```

While you technically only need one tabber per page, making this an instantiable class allows you to unit test your JavaScript.

```
describe("TabController", function() {

    var element, tabs, event;

    function FauxEvent(type, target) {
        this.type = type;
        this.target = target;
    }

    FauxEvent.prototype.preventDefault = function() {};

    describe("toggleTab", function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            element = document.createElement("div");
            tabs = new TabController().init(element);
        });

        it("shows a tab", function() {
            element.innerHTML = [
                '<a class="js-tab" data-tab-content="panel-1">Tab 1</a>',
                '<div class="js-tab-panel-1 hide"></div>'
            ].join("");

            event = new FauxEvent("click", element.firstChild);

            tabs.toggleTab(event);

            expect($(element.lastChild).hasClass("hide")).toBe(false);
        });

    });

});
```

This makes your code truly modular. You could go a step further and make the CSS class names and data attributes customizable:

```
function TabController() {
    // Maintain reference to "this" in event handlers
    this.toggleTab = this.toggleTab.bind(this);

    this.options = {
        classPrefix: "js-tab",
        hiddenClass: "hide",
        dataAttribute: "data-tab-content"
    };
}

TabController.prototype = {

    $element: null,

    options: null,

    constructor: TabController,

    init: function(element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element).on("click", "." + this.options.classPrefix, this.toggleTab);
        jQuery.extend(this.options, options || {});

        return this;
    },

    toggleTab: function(event) {
        var that = this,
            showTab = event.currentTarget.getAttribute(this.options.dataAttribute);
        event.preventDefault();

        this.$element.find("." + this.options.classPrefix).each(function() {
            var tabContent = this.getAttribute(that.options.dataAttribute);

            if (tabContent === showTab) {
                that.$element.find("." + that.options.classPrefix + "-"
                    + showTab).removeClass(that.options.hiddenClass);
            } else {
                that.$element.find("." + that.options.classPrefix + "-"
                    + tabContent).addClass(that.options.hiddenClass);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Some sample HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="js-tab" data-tab-content="content-a"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="js-tab" data-tab-content="content-b"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="js-tab-content-a">
    Content A
</div>
<div class="js-tab-content-b">
    Content B
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabs = new TabController().init(document.documentElement);
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CL8Ns/

Comment: Very nice review, more detailed than mine, welcome to CodeReview. +1

Comment: Hi Greg, this is very thorough and I really appreciated.  A few things: 1)Is this some kind of common pattern out there that perhaps you can send me a link to check out with more documentation? 2) I noticed you use "new" to instantiate which I thought should be avoided according to Crockford?

Comment: I don't recall a website outlining this pattern. It's just a pattern I keep gravitating towards. Also, take Crockford's advice (and any Guru for that matter) with a grain of salt. The `new` keyword is not bad. He's just advising to not invoke object constructors unless you have a good reason to. Code like this is a good reason to, but notice the `options` property in my code is just using JSON instead of a JavaScript "class." That's the root of what Crockford is saying.

Comment: Another thought about the `new` keyword too. Most modern browsers have performance enhancements around object oriented code, including object constructor functions, that allow JavaScript to be executed at near native speeds. If you are doing `new Foo()` a thousand times inside a loop, yeah you might see a performance issue. Otherwise, you won't.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I tried your [code](http://codepen.io/TDogg137/pen/dJkcF) but it's not quite working.  Should it work or this is just an example of your pattern?

Comment: It's an example. It might be worth your while to investigate why it's not working. :) Or, "I leave this as an exercise for the Reader."

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CL8Ns/ (also, I'll update my answer with working code)

Answer (score 4):

From a once over;

- You are selecting the content `div`s with a class name, you should select them with an `id` instead
- It is much more readable, to simply hide all content, and then show what you need.

With that I would counter propose the content to look like this:

```
<div class="js-tab-content" id='orange'>Orange Content</div>
<div class="js-tab-content hide" id='red'>Red Content</div>
<div class="js-tab-content hide" id='purple'>Purple Content</div>
```

and then `toggleTab` would be

```
toggleTab: function(e) { 

    var showTab = $(this).data("tab-content");
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".js-tab-content").hide();
    $('#' + showTab).show();
}
```

Otherwise I like your code, it's solid.